# Why can't I provide a string argument to printw in ncurses?

Tags: c++, c++11, ncurses

For an application that I'm writing, I have a string type variable that I want to display within an ncurses window:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::string mystring = "A sample string\n";

  // Entering the ncurses window
  initscr();
  printw(mystring);
  getch();
  endwin();

}
```

which throws the following error at compilation:

```
test_app.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_app.cpp:12:18: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int printw(const char*, ...)’
   printw(mystring);
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I rectify this?

Comment: The message is quite clear: You are attempting to pass a `std::string` (i.e. a `basic_string<char>` object), to a function that expects a pointer to const char. See the linked duplicate, which advises you to pass `mystring.c_str()`.

Comment: Thanks for that information. A follow up question - how then does a string that's natively passed to the `printw` function get converted to a pointer to const char? I.e., how does the call `printw("this is a string")` satisfy the function definition?

EDIT: Sorry, I see that @alex-hodges answered this exact question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some key concepts in c++:

A string literal declaration (aka "this is a string literal") has a type `const char[N]`, where N is the size of the string, including the null terminator.

`std::string != const char[]`

However, a `std::string` can be constructed with a `const char[]` using this constructor (found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)):

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Where `CharT` is your implementation specific `char` equivalent.

Now, notice how `printw` takes a `const char*`. You aren't passing a `const char *` to `printw`, you're passing a `std::string`, and they aren't implicitly convertible to a `const char *`.

We have two options to solve your problem...

1) Store the string as a char[] (aka char *):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>

int main(){
  char mystring[] = "A sample string\n"; // Can decay to a char * implicitly.

  // Entering the ncurses window
  initscr();
  printw(mystring);
  getch();
  endwin();
}
```

2) Get a representation of the `std::string` as a `char *`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::string mystring = "A sample string\n";

  // Entering the ncurses window
  initscr();
  // Since c++ 11, mystring.data() is required to return a null-terminated char *.
  // If c++ version < c++11, use mystring.c_str().
  printw(mystring.data());  
  getch();
  endwin();
}
```

Comment: You should always use `c_str()` in this case. It clarifies the intent. You intend to use C string version of this string, not as data.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Since c++11, c_str() and data() are equivalent. The intent is identically clarified in each case.